# same sql statment gives different results when run on sqlalchemy DBAPI

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The same sql select statement gives different results when i run it on sqlalchemy DBAPI and datagrip

```
CONN_STR = "postgresql://{}:{}@{}:5432/{}"\
        .format('DATABASE_USER','DATABASE_PASSWORD','DATABASE_HOST', 'DATABASE_NAME')

engine = create_engine(CONN_STR, connect_args={'sslmode': 'require'})

def run_sql_query(query):
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=engine)
    return df

example_statement = """
select count(*) 
from users
where "date" >= '2020-05-01'
"""
result = run_sql_query(example_statement)
```

This script would return a different count if i run it directly on datagrip, i tried different statements on the same table and there are always 3000 records missing on the same table

Comment: How many records are you expecting?  What is the different count you get?  Is it always the same different count?

Comment: @AndyLester yes it's always the same difference, 3000 records less than the actual

Comment: @snakecharmerb datagrip returns the correct result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the "date" column, its data type is  `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and it's set to CET timezone. When running a query on Datagrip or any other application, the application has its timezone set by default to local time (which is CET in this case). But when running the same query through SQLAlchemy, by default the timezone is set to UTC and that's why the results were different.

I fixed by passing the timezone into the connection args:

```
engine = create_engine(CONN_STR, connect_args={'sslmode': 'require', 'options': '-c timezone=cet'})
```